# NestAzureAdJwtValidatorModule: [Error] Nest cannot create the module instance

Tags: nestjs, angular14

I created my project using Angular 14 and NestJS 9. Here is the other version details:

```
Angular: 14.2.X
NestJS: 9.2.X
Node: 16.18.1
NPM: 8.19.2
nest-azure-ad-jwt-validator: 4.0.0
```

I am using NestAzureAdJwtValidatorModule for AD token validation and following the code shared here (https://www.npmjs.com/package/nest-azure-ad-jwt-validator) but I am getting below error when I put the code in app module. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
Nest cannot create the module instance.
The module at index [0] of the module "imports" array is undefined.

Potential causes:
- A circular dependency between modules. Use forwardRef() to avoid it. Read more: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency
- The module at index [0] is of type "undefined". Check your import statements and the type of the module.

Scope [AppModule]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that nest-azure-ad-jwt-validator@4 is not compatible with nestjs@9, so during compile when npm try to find the related module, it throws error. If you want to use nest-azure-ad-jwt-validator@4 in your app, better you use nestjs version 8.

Hope it helps.